# mongod service failed to restarted, 27017 port not in use - even getting address already in use error

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am not able to start mongo db service, if I try to start mongod using `systemctl restart mongod` getting error

> Job for mongod.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mongod.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Logs: `vi /var/log/mongo/mongod.log`

[image]

In log file, if I see below message, it looks like port is already in use

> exception in initAndListen std::exception: listen: Address already in use, terminating

```
netstat -apt| grep "27017"
```

> No process id.

Below is mongod status:
[image]

I am not getting any solution, your help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what is the output of `ps -Aef | grep mongo`

Comment: It worked with command `mongod --bind_ip 0.0.0.0 --fork --logpath /var/log/mongod.log`

Answer (score 0):

Trying starting mongodb on different port and with different data directory, that might be helpful, use below command to start with different port and different data directory

```
mongod --port 27027 --dbpath </path/to/your/data/directory>
```

If this work then some process might be using 27017 or or you might have mongod running on background, so first check the process id and manually kill it as below

```
ps -Aef | grep 27017
```

or

```
ps -Aef | grep mongod
```

Find the process id and kill it

```
 sudo kill -9 <processId>
```

Then try to restart it as you are doing:

```
 systemctl restart mongod
```

or:

```
 /etc/init.d/mongodb restart
```

Hope this help you out.

Answer (score 0):

One issue was the lock file used by MongoDB might have an incorrect ownership:
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 16 02:27 /var/lib/mongo/mongod.lock

Suggest you to simply removed it which will allow MongoDB to recreate it properly. This file is only needed by MongoDB if it's currently running, and ideally the file should only exist if it's running too, since it only contains a copy of the current process ID which MongoDB is running under.

The second issue will be the configuration file itself: /etc/mongod.conf.
MongoDB expects the file to be in YAML format where apparently blank spaces matter. I have share the sample configuration file which worked in our server.

Basically, each indentation should be made using two spaces for any directives underneath their parent directive.

**Additinal notes:**

For example, the "net:" heading is not indented because it's the top of its configuration tier, as where "port:" and "bindIp:" are each indented with 2 spaces since "net:" is their parent directive.
The "ssl:" directive is also indented with two spaces since its parent is "net:", but since "mode:", "CAFile:" and "PEMKeyFile:" along belong to "ssl:" they go underneath it and again each take 2 additional spaces for further indentation for a total of 4 spaces.

Finally the following mongo restart will work:

```
systemctl restart mongod
```

or

```
systemctl restart mongod.service
```

---

```html
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongo
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# how the process runs
processManagement:
  fork: true  # fork and run in background
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0  # Listen to local interface only, comment to listen on all interfaces.
  ssl:
    mode: preferSSL
    CAFile: /etc/ssl/mongodb/RootCA/root-ca.pem
    PEMKeyFile: /etc/ssl/mongodb/host.omkieitsolutions.com.pem

security:
  authorization: enabled
  clusterAuthMode: keyFile

#operationProfiling:

#replication:
"/etc/mongod.conf" 50L, 990C
```